# How to instantiate a pointer in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, image-capture

Suppose I have a pointer to type `ICScannerDevice` class for which I have allocated some memory. Now, I want to initialize it with the pointer of type `ICDevice` which is a parent class of `ICScannerDevice`. 
How do I do this?

Is the following the correct method? I guess not!

```
ICScannerDevice* scannerDevice = [[ICScannerDevice alloc] init];
scannerDevice = (ICScannerDevice*)device; // device is a pointer to ICDevice.
```

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277478/initializing-a-class-using-superclass-initializer

Answer (score 3):

> Suppose I have a pointer to type ICScannerDevice class for which I have allocated some memory.
>
> ```
> ICScannerDevice* scannerDevice = [[ICScannerDevice alloc] init];
> ```

You are mixing two things up here. *Variables* are created by *declarations*, a *declaration* can also contain an *initialisation expression*.

When you declare a variable space is allocated which can contain a *value* of the variable's *type* - whether that type is `int`, in which case the value would be a integer e.g. `42`, or `ICScannerDevice *`, in which case that value would be a reference to an allocated `ICScannerDevice` object.

So the declaration:

```
ICScannerDevice* scannerDevice
```

provides all the space you need to store a value of type `ICScannerDevice *`. The initialisation expression you give:

```
[[ICScannerDevice alloc] init];
```

is in your case redundant (and wasteful), you do not wish to create an object of type `ICScannerDevice` and store a reference to that object in `scannerDevice` as you wish to store a totally different reference in your variable:

> Now, I want to initialize it with the pointer of type ICDevice which is a parent class of ICScannerDevice.
>
> ```
> scannerDevice = (ICScannerDevice*)device; // device is a pointer to ICDevice.
> ```

This is wrong as you state that `device` holds a reference to an `ICDevice` object. As the type `ICDevice` is a parent of `ICScannerDevice` a reference to an `ICScannerDevice` can be treated as one to an `ICDevice` - aka "upcast".

However a reference known to be an object of type `ICDevice` may or may not be to an `ICScannerDevice` it might be , say, to an `ICPlotterDevice`. So you cannot directly cast - aka "downcast" and assign.

You **must** first check you actually have a reference to an `ICScannerDevice`. You do this by checking whether the type of your referenced object, using method `isKindOfObject:`, is the type `ICScannerDevice`, and you obtain that type with the `class` method:

```
if ( [device isKindOfObject:[ICScannerDevice class]] )
{
   // we have a reference to an ICScanner Device
   scannerDevice = (ICScannerDevice *)device;  // downcast and assign
    ...
}
else
{
   // device references something other than an ICScannerDevice object
   // handle this case
   ...
}
```

You also need to handle the case where the value stored in `device` is `nil` - i.e. it references nothing. You might just want to combine this with the test in the `if` and treat it as an `ICScannerDevice` reference:

```
if ( (device == nil) || [device isKindOfObject:[ICScannerDevice class]] )
```

or you may need to handle it some other way.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no point in allocating an object if you're immediately going to assign some other object to its reference.

Second, if `device` is not a `ICScannerDevice`, casting it as one is an error that may or may not cause you problems depending on what you do with it next.

So, the answer is: no, it's not really correct.

(To give you a better answer about what you **should** be doing instead would require a little more context about where `device` comes from and how you want to use `scannerDevice`.)

Comment: this isn't really an answer and more of a comment / question

Answer (score 1):

a pointer is a number that holds a memory address where the object is.

a pointer is(16/32/64 bit) and lives on the stack. just its content is on the heap.

therefore, you don't need to allocate any space for a pointer. Only for the content. Since - in your case - you get a pointer to existing content. Just copy the memory address:

```
ICScannerDevice* = (ICScannerDevice*)device; // device is a pointer to ICDevice.
```

**NOTE: remember casts don't change the content! if device isn't really a ICScannerDevice but something else, that might crash later.**