# Allow only a particular class to call init in iOS

Tags: objective-c

I was trying something new so just going through a thought process to allow only my singleton class to create new instance for other classes which are hidden behind it.

I am able to restrict to call the init method using the "unavailable" attribute along with my init method but can I create an exception that only my Singleton class can call the init method.

Answer (score 1):

> but can I create an exception that only my Singleton class can call the init method

You can't know who the caller is — see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793999/how-to-find-out-who-called-a-method) of the matter — but you can certainly hide the init method by not putting it in your header. A commonly used solution is, if possible, to have the singleton factory method call a "private" initializer and throw an exception on the "public" initializer. Of course that doesn't ultimately prevent anyone from calling the "private" initializer - sorry, Objective-C is too dynamic for that - but it makes it harder to obtain a non-singleton instance by mistake.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Ya i might need to think about some other solution but still wanna find out to what extent I can go..

Comment: The first solution here is what I use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7035136/341994 But again I would emphasize that you are just rearranging the deck chairs on the Titanic: the "private" initializer is not really private in Objective-C. You are programming by contract, not by enforcement.

Comment: I would say that its not a duplicate matt. The one question that you have linked to is the question that how to have private methods.. I already know that how I can enforce this but my question is there a way where we can have an exception for classes like a specific list who can instantiate an object.

Comment: And I told you you couldn't. So the question is answered coming from both directions. If that were possible, it would have been suggested among the answers in the other question anyway.

Comment: Then I preassume that its not a duplicate but its a feature that is restricted in objective c

Comment: Could have called it a duplicate of this, which is definitely answered by someone deep inside Apple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793999/how-to-find-out-who-called-a-method Whatever.

Comment: Matt.. This something we cannot say whether its a duplicate or not with the one marked above.. But I already checked all these answers before posting it here. And my question is pretty much in a different context.