# Can i hide or prevent alloc/init for foreign classes?

Tags: objective-c, class

Can i hide or prevent `[[Foo alloc] init]` from being used in code outside the Foo class?

I want only code to use a custom `createFooObject`, not the `alloc/init` idiom.

Is it possible to hide `alloc/init` in class?

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195078/is-it-possible-to-make-the-init-method-private-in-objective-c)