# How to forbid to inherit init method?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have been struggling to find a correct and explicit answer, so I have decided to ask it here.

I create class A and define init method there:

```
@interface A : NSObject

- (id)initWithHealth:(int)hp;

@end
```

Then I am creating class B, that inherits from class A and define another init method there:

```
@interface B : A

- (id)initWithHealth:(int)hp andDamage:(int)dmg;

@end
```

In main, when I am going to instantiate an object from class B, I will be suggested by Xcode to use either **- (id)initWithHealth:(int)hp;** OR **- (id)initWithHealth:(int)hp andDamage:(int)dmg;** init method.
How can I forbid for class B to inherit init method from class A? I want my class B to have only one init method that I define. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, but you can disable the method of A in class B: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5772821/412916

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED (thanks to Sulthan and rmaddy)

OK I have found the answer to my question, I should have used categories.
But thanks for everyone who participated.

Comment: What is `@categories`? There is no such syntax thing in Objective-C.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant just using categories, like

    @interface Blah (Category)

Answer (score 3):

You have a few choices:

Option 1 - supply a default "damage" with the old `init` method. In class `B` you would add:

```
- (id)initWithHealth:(int)hp {
    return [self initWithHealth:hp andDamage:0]; // use an appropriate default
}

- (id)initWithHealth:(int)hp andDamage:(int)dmg {
    self = [super initWithHealth:hp];
    if (self) {
        // do stuff with dmg


    return self;
}
```

Option 2 - cause a runtime error if the old `init` method is used. In class `B` you would add:

```
- (id)initWithHealth:(int)hp {
    NSAssert(0, @"Dont use this");

    return nil; // make compiler happy
}
```

Personally I think Option 1 is the better choice.

Comment: +1 Correct answer IMO, calls designated initialiser in super class and overrides super class designator in subclass as according to Apple's rules.  I wouldn't use NSASssert in option 2, I'd explicitly throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

In your subclass `B` you can explicitly define the method such that the class will not respond to it at runtime.

```
- (instancetype) initWithHealth:(int) hp {
    [self release];
    [super doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
    return nil;
}
```

This is very conventional, I've seen it used on a lot of open source projects and on some of my client's projects. I think this is preferable to @rmaddy's solution when you want to ensure the inherited method is NEVER called. If you want a sane default when the inherited init method is called, then the other code works just fine.