# How to mark designated initializers of super class "invalid" in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, designated-initializer

From the [Adapting Modern Objective-C document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html):

> If a class provides one or more designated initializers, it must implement all of the designated initializers of its superclass.

That means if I have a subclass of `NSObject` that has its own designated initializer, say

```
- (instancetype)initWithImage:(UIImage*)image NS_DESIGNATED_INITALIZER;
```

then I also need to provide an implementation of NSObjects `-init`. What should I do to mark the `-init` initializer as "invalid", i.e., nobody should call it but use `-initWithImage:` instead? What's best practice here?

#### Edit

I tried the techniques described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195078/is-it-possible-to-make-the-init-method-private-in-objective-c).

However, when I mark the superclass `-init` method as `unavailable` in the interface, the compiler still tells me that I need to overwrite the initializer of the superclass.

When I try the other techniques, i.e., raising an exception or calling `-doesNotRecognizeSelector:` inside of `-init`, I get an error stating that I need to call one of my designated initializers.