# Override init method to have singleton instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, singleton

one third party library uses my class initialisation:

```
ClassA *a = [[MyClass alloc] init]];
```

I need `MyClass` to be shared instance (aka singleton) but I can't modify 3rd party way of executing `MyClass` initialization

I was trying to override `init` method as following:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    return [[self class] sharedInstance];
}

+ (LoopMeNativeEvent *)sharedInstance
{
    static LoopMeNativeEvent *_sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [LoopMeNativeEvent new];
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}
```

but, unfortunately `new` causes `alloc init` to be executed.

Simplest way I know is to have two separate classes:

- `MyClass` which will be initialised through `alloc init`
- Separate `MySharedClass` which is singleton

Is there possibility achieve this having just one class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195078/is-it-possible-to-make-the-init-method-private-in-objective-c ?

Comment: omg... third party code will not be executed properly.. did you read question? or it's unclear? I need correct object to be returned by init, but I need it to be singleton

Comment: I suspect you have a design issue.

Comment: It's not mine design issue, sometimes, when you deal with 3rd party it happens

Comment: Maybe instead of `[LoopMeNativeEvent new]`, you may call : `[[LoopMeNativeEvent alloc] initWithCustomParam:nil];`, and with `-(id)initWithCustomParam:(NSObject *)obj{self = [super init];if (self){}return self;}` It may avoid your issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about inheritance,

Create new class named ChildClass which inherit from MyClass and add the following two methods

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static ChildClass *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       sharedInstance = [[ChildClass alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
 }
```

Comment: As I said third party code executes MyClass init method... but I want to make sure just one instance of MyClass will be ever created. Do you think your solution make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try this . It will definitely solve your problem.

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    return [[self class] sharedInstance];
}

+ (LoopMeNativeEvent *)sharedInstance {

    // structure used to test whether the block has completed or not
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;

    // initialize sharedObject as nil (first call only)
    static LoopMeNativeEvent *_sharedInstance = nil;

    // executes a block object once and only once for the lifetime of an application
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[LoopMeNativeEvent alloc] init];
    });

    // returns the same object each time
    return _sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: don't you think         _sharedInstance = [[LoopMeNativeEvent alloc] init];
is a infinity cycle?