# How to use NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER and override init?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

Okay, this is admittedly a bit of a best practice question, but I want to get it right, so hopefully someone can enlighten me:

Scenario is pretty standard, but has one twist:
I have a class in a framework I write that inherits directly from `NSObject`. It has a designated initializer with quite a few arguments, most of which are `nonnull`. Since the thing is part of a framework, I explicitly use the `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` macro (which I don't always do in smaller, personal apps).
The problem is that this leads to XCode warning me to also override `init`, i.e. the superclass's designated initializer. But additionally it demands that I call **my** designated initalizer from it, which I can't do, because I simply lack meaningful defaults for its arguments.
I don't really want to throw an exception in the "small" `init`, I'd much rather like to return `nil`.

To get rid of the warning, I added `init` as a second designated initalizer in my class's extension like so:

```
@interface MyClassName ()
// some other stuff not relevant`

-(nullable instancetype)init NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

@end
```

Now I can safely just `return nil;` in the overriden `init` method like I wanted. 
That means my documentation (I'm using appledoc) and by extension XCode's code completion won't tell someone using my framework that `init` is actually also a designated initializer (so they won't accidentally use it), but it is still there (in unit tests, for example, this could come in handy).

My question is: Are there any dangers to this besides from someone actually using it in production, happily sending messages to nil afterwards without realizing? Would this be one of the few cases where throwing an exception in init would be preferable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than just returning `nil` from `init` (and maybe adding a comment saying you shouldn't call it) – you should mark it as unavailable.

Not only will this dismiss the warning about you not overriding `NSObject`'s designated initialiser – it will also generate a compile-time error if anyone tries to call `init` instead of your designated initialiser.

To do this, you can either use the `NS_UNAVAILABLE` macro, or use the unavailable `__attribute__` as shown by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5772821/2976878). The advantage of using the `__attribute__` is you can specify a message that the compiler will present to the user.

For example:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject

-(instancetype) init __attribute__((unavailable("You cannot create a foo instance through init - please use initWithBar:")));

-(instancetype) initWithBar:(Bar*)bar NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

@end

...


Foo* fooA = [[Foo alloc] init]; // ERROR: 'init' is unavailable: You cannot create a foo instance through init - please use initWithBar:

Foo* fooB = [[Foo alloc] initWithBar:[[Bar alloc] init]]; // No error
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is definitely the preferred way. In my case I _might_ have to return `nil` due to some testing that's not defined by me, but I will definitely try to use the `__attribute__`. This is clearly the general solution anyways. I actually overlooked the question7answer you linked, because I specifically didn't want to make init "just" private. Gonna upvote now.