# How do I remove swift non-optional unwrapping with obj-c class instance?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to achieve/force this safe & clean swift syntax

```
struct PopButton: View
{
    var Label = PopEngineLabel(label:"Hello")
    var body: some View 
    {
        Text(Label.label)
    }
}
```

Ojective-c

```
@interface PopEngineLabel : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* label;

- (id)initWithLabel:(NSString*)label;

@end

@implementation PopEngineLabel 

- (id)initWithLabel:(NSString*)label
{
    if ( label )
        self.label = label;
    else
        self.label = @"<null>";
    return self;
}

@end
```

But in the swiftUI code, I get the error
`error: value of optional type 'PopEngineLabel?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'label' of wrapped base type 'PopEngineLabel'`
                `Text(Label.label)`

I can remove the errors with

- `Text(Label?.label ?? "default")`
- `Text(Label!.label)`

I'm assuming this is because all objective-c class/instances are implicitly optional.... BUT, the following code makes it non-optional, but crashes at runtime, as it hasn't done my objective-c initialiser (and `.label` is `nil`)

```
struct PopButton: View
{
    var Label = PopEngineLabel()
    var body: some View 
    {
        Text(Label.label)
    }
}
```

Can I force the user to use a constructor/initialiser AND be a non-optional in swift? (without making an intermediate swift class)

Comment: I think, to mirror your ```var Label = PopEngineLabel()``` initialiser you need an ```-init``` without any arguments on the Objective-C side.

Comment: Yeah, but really I'm trying to avoid the user being allowed to do that, as I NEED a parameter. I mentioned this one as it had a different effect to what I was expecting

Comment: Ok - I also note you did not do ```super.init``` in your initWithLabel. To hide the (default) init see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195078/is-it-possible-to-make-the-init-method-private-in-objective-c Anyhow I see you have a good answer.

Comment: @skaak thanks, that link solved the last missing piece :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nullability specifiers in Objective-C to tell Swift whether a specific property can be `nil` or not (and hence whether Swift should treat it as an `Optional` or not). By default, all reference types in Swift can be `null`, since they are pointers and hence by default, Swift treats all Obj-C pointer properties as implicitly unwrapped optionals.

However, this won't make the inherited initialiser from `NSObject` initialise `label` correctly (or make that initialiser unusable). So you need to assign a default value to `label` in the default `init` inherited from `NSObject`.

```
@interface PopEngineLabel : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic, nonnull) NSString* label;

- (instancetype)initWithLabel:(nonnull NSString*)label;
- (nonnull instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE; // disable default initialiser in Swift

@end

@implementation PopEngineLabel

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.label = @"<null>";
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithLabel:(nonnull NSString*)label {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if (label) {
            self.label = label;
        } else {
            self.label = @"<null>";
        }
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Couple of other things to bear in mind in Objective-C:

- Your init shouldn't return `id`, but `instancetype`
- You should delegate to `super init`

Comment: This works perfectly! I'm not sure if it's bad form to modify someone's answer, but the final missing part (disable `PopEngineLabel()` in swift) came from @skaak
`- (nonnull instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;`
stops me from using the default constructor

Comment: @SoylentGraham feel free to edit my answer with that update

Comment: For any future readers (ie. me), the objc member won't trigger any swiftui changes. To do that I need an intermediatry `Observable` swift object. I write a `@State` dirty variable and then a getter/setter to access & modify the obj-c member. Then [in swift] overload a `OnChanged` objc function (called in objc field setter). That function modifies the dirty variable and swiftui's state changes.